# How to Kill Sand When it Hits the Ground?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I have a custom Mob I'm making in 1.11, but I need to make it so when it hits you sand spawns on your head until you kill it (It will be riding on your head until you kill it)I need the sand to /kill itself or something when it hits the floor

Answer (score -1):

Execute @e[type=FallingBlock] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-0.1 ~ air 0 kill @e[r=0,c=0]

Comment: This will kill falling sand when it's in the air, not when it hits the ground as was requested. `c=0` causes the parameter to be ignored, and can potentially kill any entity within its radius of 0 (including the player); `c=1` is specifically used to re-target the command sender. As well, the correct ID is `falling_block` (or `FallingSand` pre-1.11).